# how to check wether an label with "for" prop excists?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have an HTML label:

```
<label class="label-radio-button-detail-gray" for="Metallic Black">
</label>
```

And an array i get returned to me from an ajax post:

```
Array [ "Metallic Black" ]
```

I want to check if a label with a for="Metallic Black" excists on the page then add a class.

This is what i have:

```
).done(function(response){
   console.log(response);
   if(response.length > 0) {
      response.forEach(function(item){

       });
   }
});
```

How do i achieve this?

Comment: `Metallic Black` is not a valid value of `for`: _"If the attribute is specified, the attribute's value must be the ID of a labelable element"_ ([W3](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#attr-label-for)) and an id is not allowed to contain spaces: _"When specified on HTML elements, the id attribute value must be unique amongst all the IDs in the element's tree and must contain at least one character. The value must not contain any ASCII whitespace."_ ([HTML Standard](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#the-id-attribute))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use below solution.

```js
var response = ["Metallic Black"];

if (response.length > 0) {
  response.forEach(function(item) {
    $("label").each(function() {
      if ($(this).prop("for") == item) {
        $(this).addClass("your-class");
      }
    });
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<label class="label-radio-button-detail-gray" for="Metallic Black"> Metallic Black
</label>
<br/>
<label class="label-radio-button-detail-gray" for="Metallic Black1"> Metallic Black1
</label>
```

Comment: Thanks, this is great!

Answer (score 0):

How about with jquery?

```
var label = $('label[for="Metallic Black"]').addClass("new_class");
```

```js
var label = $('label[for="Metallic Black"]').addClass("new_class");
```

```css
.new_class{
color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="Metallic Black" class="">sdfsdfsf</label>
```

small example provided below.

Comment: This doesn't check wether the for has "Metallic Black"

Answer (score 0):

A pure javascript solution. Below ternary will return truthy statement ("foo exists") if there a dom elemnt with `for="Metallic Black"` attribute found. Otherwise it will evaluate foo to `undefined` which is falsey.

```js
var foo = document.querySelector('[for="Metallic Black"]');
console.log(foo ? "foo exists" : "no entry found");
```

```html
<label class="label-radio-button-detail-gray" for="Metallic Black">
</label>
```